# How to do PasswordBox validation?

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, passwordbox

I followed [this tutorial](http://briannoyes.net/2015/03/04/wpf-using-passwordbox-in-mvvm/) on how to bind a `PasswordBox` with the `ViewModel`, but I wanted to add some validation on the `PasswordBox` like the `TextBox` has:

[image: ValidationError]

How can I achieve this, still using this method for `PasswordBox` binding?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Style Your `PasswordBox` and in `Triggers` We can Update the `Style`.

```
<PasswordBox>
  <PasswordBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFocused,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                               Value="False" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsError}"
                               Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Red" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </PasswordBox.Style>
</PasswordBox>
```

in this Code `IsError` Property will be your `ViewModel` Property To find weather this Password has any Errors. Then Update the `BorderBrush` of your `PasswordBox`.

Comment: I did this already in my code, the problem is that the border brush is inside the PasswordBox and the validation Adorner is in the outside, so there is a clear visual difference when there is a textbox near a passwordbox

Comment: Why the MultiDataTrigger? Just a DataTrigger to IsError will do, right?